# Web service or direct connection to the database?

Tags: android, web-services

I'm new in Android Development and I want to know which is better a web service or direct connection to the database (not local database). The app will need to do alot of things with charts and etc. There is alot of information to be pull from the database. If you can give me any tips I'll be thankful.

Comment: I used Direct connection it's better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best Performance is to store the data from WebService in local SQLite DB: but it would be complexer
you should ask every time you start your app, if theres new data in WebService to download and store it again.

Comment: I know, but the app will work offline too. But I have to connect to sync the data, so, to syn the data which are the best ways? I have to also send info from the local SQLite DB to the Web DB. There is DB Manager here where I work to help with this, but he doesn't know nothing about Android.

Comment: you could generate a random hash-value on server side. Download at every start the hashvalue from Server (in online Mode). Save it in SharedPrefs, and you could check at every start of the Application if its the same value or it has changed. If it has changed its hashvalue, you know there are new data available and download them, if its the same value just take the data from the local SQLite DB.

Answer (score 1):

If U have a good idea about PHP,JSON you can go for it,else u can use a Direct Conncetion

Comment: The people that I work with knows alot about, thank you.